# How to expand tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits numClasses

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm working on a network which should be able to learn new classes on the fly. This means that the number of output classes increases during training. To do this I reinitialize the last layer of the network once a new class appears with one node more. It all works well and the last layer increases in size during training. The problem I have now is whenever a new label shows up which is out of the initial range tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits throws this error:

"*Received a label value of 7 which is outside the valid range of [0, 7).  Label values: 0 6 5 2 0 2 1 6 4 2 6 4 3 4 5 7 5 7 1 4 5 4 6 1 1 6 7 6 7 5 6 3 4 0 7 0 0 1 7 3 1 2 4 3 2 7 3 3 4 7 0 0 7 3 6 5 0 3 0 7 2 2 2 3 2 2 0 7 2 3 4 2 2 6 0 3 6 5 4 1 6 5 0 6 1 7 4 7 7 2 3 0 5 6 3 7 1 1 1 0 0 3 7 6 5 1 4 6 0 0 4 7 1 0 3 0 1 4 4 6 1 0 6 6 2 3 0 7 2 7 6 2 7 0 2 6 1 5 2 7 6 4 6 6 7 5 2 2 0 7 6 7 7 4 1 7 3 5 2 5 2 3 7 6 2 0 3 6 7 6 5 3 5 4 4 7 5 7 5 7 6 3 6 5 4 4 7 7 1 0 4 3 7 5 6 2 7 2 3 0*"

I am testing on the CIFAR-10 dataset and started training with 6 classes. After adding the 7th class the last layer has size [batchsize,8] but tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits does not recognize that there is another output node now. When I just grow the last layer without adding new classes to the input batches everything works fine. Is there some kind of trick to tell tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits that numClasses has increased?